# Rspec - expecting one among specific outputs

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-expectations

Working on rspec(2.14.1), rspec-core (2.14.8) & rspec-expectations(2.14.5) versions

Need to expect one of two specific outputs. Tried below statements and got respective errors,

```
expect(fruit).should be_in('Apple','Mango')
```

Error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `should' for #<RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x007fa63c4336d8>
```

and

```
expect(fruit).to eq('Apple').or(eq('Mango'))
```

and

```
expect(fruit).to include('Apple').or(eq('Mango'))
```

Error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `or' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Eq:0x007fa63c431630>
```

Searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. Is there a way to do it without having to update rspec to 3?

Comment: Thanks psantos & SteveTurczyn, both the solutions worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
expect(fruit).to be_in(['Apple','Mango'])
```

You are expecting an element (`fruit`) to be in an array (`['Apple', 'Mango']`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do...

```
expect(['Apple', 'Mango'].include?(fruit)).to be true
```